# jquery: eventObject.pageY and scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using eventObject.pageY to get the current mouse position when the event is fired. But I noticed the number is relative to the document but not the viewport.

I want to get the pageY relative to the viewport(when vertical scrollbar appears it has difference to the pageY relative to the document), how to get that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
eventObject.pageY - $(window).scrollTop()
```